# Validation fails for [DataType(DataType.Email)] in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, data-annotations

It seems that the internal validation in the DataType DataAnnotation for DataType.Email fails when the email address starts with a number.  I ran into this when a user with a 1234Something@gmail.com style email address tried to register on my site and their address was reported as "invalid".  After some experimentation, it seems that the leading digit is the culprit.

I haven't been able to find anything about this online.  Anyone know if it's a known issue, or did I by chance discover a new bug? :)  Is this something about the standard email address format that Microsoft got right and Google is doing incorrectly?  Is there a work-around?

Scott

Comment: `DataType` is more of a UI helper when generating the templates or selecting which EditorFor template to use. What is your actual attribute on the property?

Comment: Check this Example: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Email-model-validation-with-DataAnnotations-and-DataType-In-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 1):

According to the [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4) specification there doesn't seem to be any restriction to limiting email addresses to not start with a digit.

Reading [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_address) also implies it being completely valid.

To test this I created a Live.com email account that started with a number and it went through no problem.

So I suppose this is an issue. The best way to correct it would be to make you're own regex for the email.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a regex validator

```
[RegularExpression(@"^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$", ErrorMessage="Invalid email")]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

This regex was taken from Microsoft's source in MVC3. It's from the futures project and attached to a validator called `EmailAddressAttribute`